# Как обнулить локальную переменную в цикле python

Tags: python, циклы, переменные

Как мне обнулять переменную `r` в последнем цикле при каждом проходе цикла `x`?

```
    r = 0  
    for x in range(p):
            size = input().split(' ')
            h = size[0]
            l = size[1]

            for i in range(int(h)):
                arr.append(input())

            for i in range(len(arr)):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
                        if j % 2 == 0:
                            if not(arr[i][j] == "R"):
                                r+=5
                        elif j % 2 != 0:
                            if not(arr[i][j] == "G"):
                                r+=3
```

Если напишу `r = 0` после открытия первого цикла `r` в последнем цикле не обнулиться

Comment: думаю будет лучше если вы отметите место в коде где у вас проблема.

Comment: Напишите перед "закрытием".

Comment: Вставьте обнуление там, где считаете нужным, расскажите, что получается в итоге и расскажите что вы хотите получить. Если поставить `r = 0` после `for x in range(p):`, то при каждом новом проходе этого цикла, переменная будет обнуляться

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, что вы хотите вашей программой сделать, но попробую вам помочь.

Ваша структура циклов такая:

```
for x in range(p):
        for i in range(int(h)):
        for i in range(len(arr)):
                for j in range(len(arr[i])):
```

Значит, существуют 4 подходящие места для команды `r = 0`:

- после первого `for`,
- после второго `for`,
- после третьего `for`,
- после четвёртого `for`.

Попробуйте каждое из них, и увидите.